# MySQL: is AND conditional or logical?

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

If I run such a query in MySQL:

```
SELECT field FROM table WHERE field1=42 AND field2 LIKE '%beer%';
```

Will every row be parsed for having "beer" in `field2` or only those whose `field1`=42?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the query plan and what indexes you have on the table. Try putting `EXPLAIN` before your query and MySQL will tell you more. Generally speaking though, if `field1` is indexed, then `LIKE` should only be performed for those rows where `field1` is 42.

Comment: Thanks, I have never seen `EXPLAIN` before!